# Rails rake db:create does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I come from a computer science and programming background, and I am familiar with a *nix CLI.

I am new to ruby on rails, and I am doing an online bootcamp.  One of my lessons has me creating a new rails application.  It starts out with the following commands to create a new rails application and create the database:

```
$ rails new bloccit -T
$ cd bloccit
$ rake db:create
```

When I run the `rake` command, the process just hangs.  I let it run for 30 minutes, and it just sat there.  When I do a hard interrupt, I get the following stack trace:

```
^C/Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:99:in `gets': Interrupt
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:99:in `verify_server_version'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `run'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:37:in `warm_run'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/run.rb:26:in `call'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mikekeathley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mikekeathley/code/bloccit/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rake:3:in `load'
from bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
```

I understand the stack trace: on line 99 in the run.rb file, the method gets is getting stuck.  I just don't know anything about spring.

I am running Ruby 2.2.1p85, Rails 4.2.1, and sqlite3 1.3.10.

Comment: Follow this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/25172613/3863146

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby on rails console hanging when loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027284/ruby-on-rails-console-hanging-when-loading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop spring by using command

```
bin/spring stop
```

and then run rake command again. It would fix this issue.