# Can't start IRB intermittently because of activerecord error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, irb

I'm having trouble reliably running the Rails console. Usually I can start it it once after restarting my machine, but after quitting, I can't start it again. It looks like the problem is with activerecord.

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 82527
/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Comment: Ok, looks like this is a common issue with `spring`. Solution is to kill it with `bin/spring stop`. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027284/ruby-on-rails-console-hanging-when-loading

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of the sqlite3 gem:

```
bundle update
```

Also get the latest version of sqlite3-ruby:

```
brew install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

When that happens to me what I normally do is  grep command in following way,

ps aux | grep rails

and then

kill -9 {process_id}