# Rails hanging when trying to generate controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason I can't seem to use the `rails generate` command. Been trying to generate a controller called `home` and another one called `artists` but it seems to keep hanging.

When I cancel the request, I get the following stack:

```
^C/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `verify_server_version'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in `run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in `warm_run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `call'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/Code/spotify-tres/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/username/Code/spotify-tres/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

No clue what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: show the command

Comment: Can you try `spring stop` before running the rails command?

Comment: Command i'm using is `rails g controller home`. It looks like spring stop before running the command made it work. Why is that?

Comment: bugs in spring.

Answer (score 9):

Spring bug. You can find more information here https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/265 and [ruby on rails console hanging when loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027284/ruby-on-rails-console-hanging-when-loading)

Two main options:

1. Stop (or restart spring) `bin/spring stop`
2. Try reinstalling in a clean rvm environment

Comment: Worked for me even on rails 5.2.3